# Deleting duplicate edges from edge table

Tags: postgresql

I have thought of following query but it seems syntactically wrong.

```
 delete from table where geom_line in(select distinct(a.geom_line) from table 
 a ,table b where a.source=b.target and b.source=a.target);
```

my idea is to delete on of the edges of there exists edges where same source to target is target to source in another edge that is two edges for nodes 1 and 2, from 1->2 and 2->1 and i will delete one of them.

When running only the subquery i get distinct edges with there "geom_lines" as 2000 rows while when i run the whole query 4000 rows are deleted what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be as simple as

```
DELETE FROM "table" a
USING "table" b
WHERE a.source = b.target
  AND a.target = b.source
  AND a.source > a.target;
```

Comment: hi,I've updated the question if you could look into it